Why is this problem of Unity collision count happening?
I'm counting down the collisionCount to get button out if I crash three times.
However, the collisionCount is not counted properly, so it continues to be counted as 1.
I'm asking questions because I don't know what the problem is. Please help.

public class ItemPickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject player;
    private StartMng mng; 

    int collisionCount = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        this.player = GameObject.Find("player");
        mng = FindAnyObjectByType<StartMng>(); 

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject == player) 
        {
            collisionCount++;

            Debug.Log($"충돌 횟수: {collisionCount}");

            Destroy(gameObject);  
            mng.ActivePanel(collisionCount); 

            if (collisionCount == 3)
            {
                mng.StartBtnClick();
            }

        }
    }
 }

CollisionCount should be added 1 by 1 in 1, 2, 3. But this code doesn't add up.
CollisionCount continues to be 1.
I wonder what to do with this little error.

Is it definitely the same instance of the ItemPickUp class each time? If not, then the collisionCount variable needs to have a wider scope.

Are you saying that collisionCount should be global variable?

Yes. You can try it and see if it works; if not, come back and let us know :)

If I understand correctly, the ItemPickUp class is attached to multiple items in your game. That means each item has an instance of your variable collisionCount. What you can do is create a new script like a PlayerController and detect when you collide with ItemPickUp and increase your collisionCount inside the PlayerController.

Ok, I'll try everything you've answered!!

I solved it! Thank you very much, but I have a small question. I'm dealing with a collision on ItempPickup right now. Destroy runs when it collision , and the panel turns on as collisionCount increases. Why do I have to increase collisionCount on PlayerController? Is it because of the instance of variable collisioncount?

@jinichi As you suspect, you need to have only one instance of the variable collisionCount. If you have more than one instance then they can all have different values even though the variable name appears to be the same.

Defining collisionCount as a global variable seems like a good idea but it can be detrimental to the management of code throughout the project. Consider the following suggestions:
You need to change the way collisionCount is declared, that is to say change "int collisionCount = 0;" into:
private static int collisionCount = 0;

Here is why do so:
1. Characteristics of Static Variables
When you want a variable to be shared among all instances of a class, you can use static variables. In your example, collisionCount needs to be shared among all ItemPickUp instances, so declaring it as a static variable is appropriate.
Additionally, static variables can maintain their state even if objects are destroyed. For instance, after an ItemPickUp object is destroyed, the value of collisionCount remains intact and can continue to be used by newly created objects.
2. Characteristics of Private Variables
Private variables can only be accessed within the class they are declared in and cannot be accessed from outside the class. This helps encapsulate data, preventing external code from accidentally modifying the variable's value. In your example, collisionCount is declared as a private variable to ensure it can only be modified within the ItemPickUp class, thus protecting the integrity of the variable.
Relevant resources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members
Static members are shared among all instances of a class. To declare a static member, use the static keyword. You access a static member by using the name of the class instead of an instance of the class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields
A field can be declared as a static field, which means that the field is shared by all instances of the class. When you use the static keyword to declare a static field, the field's value is the same across all instances of the class, and the field is accessed directly from the class, rather than from an instance of the class.

Would it be necessary to use Interlocked.Increment rather than ++ to increment the value reliably?

Well, that's a good idea considering thread safety but not necessary. @Andrew Morton

@AndrewMorton Unity logic is strictly single-threaded, locking is never needed

You should track this value somewhere that isn't in the pickup itself.
This is what's happening;

Your 3 pickups are instantiated, each with their own value of collisionCount at a value of 0.

You pick up an item, incrementing its instance variable count from 0 to 1, log this, then destroy the object (along with its variables and data).

You pick up a totally separate item and increment its instance variable count from 0 to 1 again.


To fix this, store the collisionCount in some single location. For instance, on the player.
Like this:
// Remove the field "collisionCount"

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject == player)
    {
        player = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<__PlayerComponnet__>();

        player.collisionCount++;

        Debug.Log($"충돌 횟수: {player.collisionCount}");

        Destroy(gameObject);
        mng.ActivePanel(player.collisionCount);

        if (player.collisionCount == 3)
        {
            mng.StartBtnClick();
        }

    }
}

